# Verb use in relation to the place of speech

Tags: verbs

I have some doubts about one of the verbs used in the following sentence, in which a woman is talking to a man.

- *I will **come** (to) visit you at your house*.

Some context: the conversation takes place in the park today, and the woman will visit the man tomorrow.

Is this use of "*come*" correct and idiomatic?

Besides, can I delete "*to*"?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: The articles referred to by Professor Lawler in the duplicate [How to identify deictic center for distinguishing the choice of 'come'/'go'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/338795/how-to-identify-deictic-center-for-distinguishing-come-go) provide an in-depth answer.

Comment: The come/go custom is different in English than in Spanish.  In English, if I talk about you transporting yourself to the place where I am, that must use the word "come."  And if I talk about you starting where I am, or some other place, and transporting yourself to a certain place, that will be with the word "go."  Similarly, if I talk about my own movement.  I go to the hospital: I come home from school.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, *come* is appropriate here. Although the man is not in his house at the time of speaking, she assumes that he will be at home tomorrow; she will come to the place where he is. (I wouldn't omit *to*, but maybe an American would?)

If someone were to go to his house *now*, while he is out, *go* would be appropriate.